# Execute java sql statements in sequence before another statements

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

The error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "food_order" violates foreign key constraint "food_order_invoice_id_fkey"
  Detail: Key (invoice_id)=(2) is not present in table "invoice".
```

First I insert my data to invoice table and then insert the id of that as reference for another. I want these statements executed sequentially.

This is my code:

```
public static void insertInvoice(Invoice invoice) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = DatabaseConnectionPostgre.connection();
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    PaymentType paymentType = invoice.getPaymentType();
    String query = null;
    switch (paymentType){
        case Cash:
            query = "insert into cash_invoice values(" +
                    "'" + invoice.getId() + "', " +
                    "'" + invoice.getDate() + "', " +
                    "'" + invoice.getTotalPrice() + "', " +
                    "'" + invoice.getCustomer().getId() + "', " +
                    "'" + invoice.getInvoiceStatus() + "', " +
                    "'" + ((CashInvoice) invoice).getDeliveryFee() + "' " +
                    ")";
            break;
        case Cashless:
            query = "insert into cash_invoice values(" +
                    "'" + invoice.getId() + "', " +
                    "'" + invoice.getDate() + "', " +
                    "'" + invoice.getTotalPrice() + "', " +
                    "'" + invoice.getCustomer().getId() + "', " +
                    "'" + invoice.getInvoiceStatus() + "', " +
                    "'" + ((CashlessInvoice) invoice).getPromo() + "' " +
                    ")";
            break;
    }
    statement.executeUpdate(query);
    for (Food food:
         invoice.getFoods()) {
        query = "insert into food_order( food_id, invoice_id) values(" +
                "'" + food.getId() + "', " +
                "'" + invoice.getId() + "' " +
                ")";
        statement.execute(query);
    }
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `INSERT INTO invoice`. Out of topic: use `PreparedStatement`

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The error mentions table `invoice`, but your code is inserting into table `cash_invoice`. Please provide the necessary DDL to reproduce the problem. Also, never ever concatenate values into a query string: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use a prepared statement.